in Ib Insync how to cancel a ticker? I can't get a tickid
I can't find anyway to identify the specific ticker stream in order to cancel it properly..? I'm sure its simple but I'm being dumb.
In the vanilla IB API you can specify a tickid, but it seems Insync is taking care of it somehow. The problem is I need to cancel marketdata streams as well as start them.
Here's my code:
from ib_insync import *

# Connect to IB Gateway or TWS
ib = IB()
ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 7496, clientId=5)

# Define the contract for the index
instr = Stock(symbol='SPY', exchange='SMART', currency='USD')

# Request market data
ticker = ib.reqMktData(instr, snapshot=False, regulatorySnapshot=False)

# Wait for data to populate
ib.sleep(1)

# Access the tickId from the ticker object
tick_id = ticker.contract.conId  
print(f"Contract ID (conId): {tick_id}")

# Print current market data
print(f"Last price: {ticker.last}")
print(f"Bid: {ticker.bid}")
print(f"Ask: {ticker.ask}")

# Cancel the market data stream
ib.cancelMktData(tick_id)

# Disconnect
ib.disconnect()

I get the error: cancelMktData: No reqId found for contract 0.
I have tried adding a tickid:
ticker = ib.reqMktData(stock, '', False, False, TICKID)

but that doesnt seem to work either.

Change ib.cancelMktData(tick_id) to ib.cancelMktData(instr)
Based on ib_insync source code:
 def cancelMktData(self, contract: Contract):
    """
    Unsubscribe from realtime streaming tick data.

    Args:
        contract: The exact contract object that was used to
            subscribe with.
    """
    ticker = self.ticker(contract)
    reqId = self.wrapper.endTicker(ticker, 'mktData') if ticker else 0
    if reqId:
        self.client.cancelMktData(reqId)
    else:
        self._logger.error(
            'cancelMktData: ' f'No reqId found for contract {contract}')

